# Nvwa leak detection library crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leak-detector

Nvwa crashes on free calls in its delete operator overrides, especially on simulator, with error:

`malloc: *** error for object [hexadecimal address]: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about compilation settings on the target that you use to build the library.
Nvwa uses platform-specific macros to recognise available threading libraries and it so happens that _PTHREADS is not normally defined on iOS and I did not allow C++11 mutexes by NOT defining NVWA_USE_CXX11_MUTEX set to 1. So we have few alternatives, either define _PTHREADS, allow use of C++11 mutexes or change Nvwa code to also check for _POSIX_THREADS macro... 
One of the places that absolutely require "proper" mutexes is the update of allocation list that is used to report leaks (in debug_new.cpp). Without synchronising there, next element pointers are bound to eventually point to released memory and use-after-free is just a matter of time.

Comment: As a side-note, it's a shame that NVWA documentation is all but non-existent. Had they included at least a makefile or something, which would give me insight into possible options, I would not have to browse their code. Another drawback is that NVWA reports false-positives on iOS because of third party libraries that have "static" caching schemes (general problem of this approach to leak detection, same thing happens with CRTDBG under Visual Studio) but that is off-topic here...

Answer (score 0):

Your leak detection library apparently and ironically has a heap corruption bug, likely use-after-free.  I suggest you use Instruments or malloc history to determine what that address previously corresponded to and then audit the lifecycle of that allocation and pointers to it.

Comment: If so, then why is enabling threading support fixing the crashes? Pure luck? Yes, the end result of disabled thread sychronization is the same, heap corruption.

Comment: Well, your advice, although rather generic, might have been helpful. I've updated my answer with example of what was going wrong.